# How to express dependence on a shared library when making multithreaded

Tags: makefile, shared-libraries

I use a shared `library.so` in order to avoid to remake executables (which are linked against it) when only the implementation (`library.cpp`), but not the interface (`library.hpp`), has changed, i.e.

```
obj/library.o:    library.cpp library.hpp
lib/library.so:    obj/library.o

program        :    program.cpp library.hpp
                $(CXX) program.cpp -Llib -lrary
```

Thus, `program` does not depend on `library.cpp` or `library.so`. However, when making it from scratch (rather than remaking it because of changes to some files), `library.so` must be made before `program`. This can be ensured by setting:

```
default:    library.so program
```

But when using `make -j` this is broken.

So what is the correct way to 1) ensure `library.so` is made before `program` but 2) avoid re-making `program` if only `library.cpp` has changed?

Comment: What does multithreading have to do with this question?

Comment: @EtanReisner `make -j` uses several threads: it may start making `program` on one thread before finishing making `library` on others.

Comment: It starts multiple processes actually, not threads, but that's not really relevant to the point either. Your makefile, as written, is broken when running `make program` in a clean directory having nothing to do with `make -j` or multiple processes/etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for what you want is an order-only prerequisite.

From the [Types of Prerequisites](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types) section of the GNU make Manual:

> Occasionally, however, you have a situation where you want to impose a specific ordering on the rules to be invoked *without* forcing the target to be updated if one of those rules is executed. In that case, you want to define *order-only* prerequisites. Order-only prerequisites can be specified by placing a pipe symbol (|) in the prerequisites list: any prerequisites to the left of the pipe symbol are normal; any prerequisites to the right are order-only:
>
> ```
> targets : normal-prerequisites | order-only-prerequisites
> ```

Comment: this looks exactly what I want ... will try it soon.